# Syntax error when using OFFSET, ORDER BY (Bit and Date DESC) and WHERE in my SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a news article database `tblNewsEvents` as so:

```
newsID  |  newsSticky   |   newsDate              |   newsContent
--------+---------------+-------------------------+---------------
1       |   true        |   10/09/2017 18:05:22   |   VarChar text
2       |   false       |   10/09/2017 18:00:53   |   VarChar text
3       |   false       |   10/09/2017 18:04:18   |   VarChar text
4       |   false       |   10/09/2017 18:03:57   |   VarChar text
```

And another table, so a user can upload images with the news story. It adds the `newsID` of the story to `newsSyncID` column in the `tblNewsEventsPic` database so that it knows which story and images are connected.

```
picID   |  picOne       |   picTwo      |   syncNewsEventID
--------+---------------+---------------+-------------------
1       |   /path.jpg   |   /path2.jpg  |   1
2       |   /path.jpg   |   /path2.jpg  |   2
3       |   /path.jpg   |   /path2.jpg  |   3
4       |   /path.jpg   |   /path2.jpg  |   4
```

How can I sort through `newsDate DESC` and `newsSticky = true/1` so that the most recent stories and/or news sticky stories are at the top?

I get the same syntax error near `WHERE`, no matter how I try and phrase the query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblNewsEvents 
LEFT JOIN tblNewsEventsPic ON tblNewsEvents.newsID = tblNewsEventsPic.syncNewsEventID 
ORDER BY newsDate DESC 
    OFFSET 1 ROWS 
WHERE newsSticky = 1;
```

`OFFSET 1 ROWS` is enabled as the most recent news story is featured elsewhere.

I use `LEFT JOIN` so that the picture path from `picOne` is used alongside the News article.

But sorting by bit is proving a challenge.

Trying to find [help](https://www.essentialsql.com/using-offset-and-fetch-with-the-order-by-clause/) online, with my syntax error I searched for 'How to use OFFSET and WHERE' but articles were not helpful.

Comment: `WHERE` just has to come *before* the `ORDER BY` - just check [the official Microsoft Docs on `SELECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql) for the details ...

Comment: Thanks. I think the above query will only show newsSticky items? Is a multiple ORDER BY here my best bet?

Comment: Yes, don't remove the false rows, just order them last: `order by newsSticky desc, newsDate desc`

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblNewsEvents LEFT JOIN
     tblNewsEventsPic
     ON tblNewsEvents.newsID = tblNewsEventsPic.syncNewsEventID 
WHERE newsSticky = 1
ORDER BY newsDate DESC 
OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS
```

The order of the clauses matters.

Comment: Do I have to use FETCH or can I stick to original? `WHERE newsSticky = 1 ORDER BY newsDate DESC OFFSET 1 ROWS`

Comment: My mistake, it does return data but ONLY newsSticky items. Not all of them, with news sticky at the top...